# How to set a field of the model in view using generic views?

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I have a model, which has an author `ForeignKey`, as such:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    # ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I want the `author` field to be set automatically when creating appointment to currently logged-in user. In other words, the author field should not appear in my Form class:

```
class AppointmentCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        exclude = ('author')
```

There are two problems:

1. How to access the form in generic CreateView and set the `author`?
2. How to tell the form to save the excluded field along with the values read from user input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified my generic view subclass as such:

```
class AppointmentCreateView(CreateView):        
    model=Appointment
    form_class = AppointmentCreateForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        # the actual modification of the form
        form.instance.author = request.user

        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

There are few important parts here:

- I modified form `instance` field, which holds the actual model that's going to be saved.
- You can of course get rid of the `form_class`
- The post method that I've needed to modify was two classes above in hierarchy, so I needed to incorporate the base code **and** the `self.object = None` line, merging the overload and base into one function (I'm not calling `super` in `post`).

I think it's a good way to solve pretty common problem, and once again I don't have to write my own custom view.

Answer (score 7):

The following seem slightly simpler. Note that self.request is set in [`View.as_view`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.6/django.views.generic.base/View/)

```
class AppointmentCreateView(CreateView):        
    model=Appointment
    form_class = AppointmentCreateForm

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        form = super(AppointmentCreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        # the actual modification of the form
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return form
```

Comment: the right signature woudn't be `def get_form(self, form_class**=None**): ` ?

Comment: You are absolutly right @AllanVital, it has been like you write since Django 1.8 (I stopped using Django right about when 1.7 came out)