# Django class based generic views: setting a field to initial value based on context

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

I have a set of related models in a Django 1.5 app: `Events` that have `EventSessions`, and `EventSessionRegistrations` that belong to `EventSessions`.

I'm struggling to create a class based generic view for a user-facing registration form, where a user registers to attend an `EventSession`. Specifically the problem is around excluding the field for which `EventSession` the registration is for from being rendered in the form, whilst still setting that value based on the context and/or URL.

I'll try to explain via a use-case first:

1. User goes to `'/events/foo/bar'`, where `foo` is the `Event`, and `bar` is the `EventSession`.
2. At this URL, there is a link to register for the `EventSession`, leading to `'/events/foo/bar/register/'`. Form for the `EventSessionRegistration` model is displayed, but without selecting the `EventSession` in the UI, since that information is already "set" by the URL.
3. After successful form submission, user is redirected to a static "Thanks"-page.

To acheive this, I have the following view code (lots of other imports etc excluded):

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class RegistrationCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = SessionRegistrationForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'
    template_name = 'events/registration_create.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Set the context of which Event, and which EventSession.
           Return 404 if either Event or EventSession is not public."""
        context = super(RegistrationCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        s = get_object_or_404(
            EventSession,
            event__slug=self.kwargs['event_slug'],
            event__is_public=True,
            slug=self.kwargs['session_slug'],
            is_public=True)
        context['session'] = s
        context['event'] = s.event
        return context
```

URL pattern for this view (included from a base `urls.py`):

```
url(r'^(?P<event_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<session_slug>[\w-]+)/register/$',
    RegistrationCreate.as_view(), name="event_session_registration"),
```

In the ModelForm, I've tried to convert the ForeignKey `session` on EventSessionRegistration field (pointing to `EventSession`) to show a `HiddenInput()`-widget:

```
class SessionRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = EventSessionRegistration
        widgets = {
            'session': HiddenInput()
        }
```

But I still don't know how to set the initial value of that field to the id of the `'session'` value that I set in `get_context_data`. I've tried setting `self.initial = {'session': s.id}` inside `get_context_data`, but I'm guessing that the `initial` attribute is already used to construct the form at that point.

Any ideas on the best way to acheive this? What am I missing?

Comment: But if you're getting a `EventSession` from the database it *should* already have an `id` so that you could do this in your template `session.id`.

Comment: @limelights Yup, I've been playing around with that, creating a hidden `<input>` and adding session.id to that, but then I had to exclude the `session` field from the form, causing Django to ignore that field anyway when the form is posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659508/how-in-django-set-field-of-the-model-in-view-using-generic-views?rq=1), which deals with the same issue.
I ended up with the following overridden post-function in the view, and manually outputting the session id in the template in a hidden field:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = None
    evt_session = get_object_or_404(
        EventSession, pk=int(self.request.POST['session']))
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)

    form.instance.session = evt_session

    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Also, I found [ccbv.co.uk](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/), which is a great resource for finding out about all the methods and attributes in CBV:s, which gave guidance as to how the override should be structured.