# Django form validation fails if value set using form.instance

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, django-generic-views

I am trying to assign currently logged in user as an attribute to a field of a modelform instance using generic views. I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659508/how-to-set-a-field-of-the-model-in-view-using-generic-views) SO post and did override `post` method but it was giving me an error that CreatedBy field was required. Also I have gone through `mro` on [ccbv](http://ccbv.co.uk/) many times. View as below.

```
class PostCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    success_message = "Post Updated"
    success_url = '/home/'

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        """
        Returns an instance of the form to be used in this view.
        """
        form = super(PostCreate, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.instance.CreatedBy=User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)     
        return form

    def get_initial(self):
        """
        Returns the initial data to use for forms on this view.
        """
        self.initial = {'CreatedBy':  User.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)}
        return self.initial.copy()

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        """
        Returns the keyword arguments for instantiating the form.
        """
        kwargs = {
        'initial': self.get_initial(),
        'prefix': self.get_prefix(),
        }
        if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
            kwargs.update({
            'data': self.request.POST,
            'files': self.request.FILES,
        })

        return kwargs
```

The reason I did override all these methods is to check the availability of initial dict in every method. It is available in every method but still form validation fails. But I think its better not to set values in `get_initial(self)` since I do not prepopulate form fields with existing data of any saved object, rather I want to `update a field of an initialized form with User object of logged in user`. I have gone through flow of control in `ipdb` but enden up with same error.

```
ipdb> form.initial={'CreatedBy':User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)}
ipdb> form.fields['CreatedBy']=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id) 
ipdb> form.instance.CreatedBy=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
ipdb> form.is_valid()
False
ipdb> form.instance.CreatedBy
<User: userone>
ipdb> form.fields['CreatedBy']
<User: userone>
ipdb> form.initial
{'CreatedBy': <User: userone>}
```

Please notice that I am not looking for a manipulated `form_valid(self)` method.
I am caught up with this for hours. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Whats inside of `form.errors`? (btw `request.user` is the same result as your `User.objects.get(id..)` query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that created_by is still required is because you have not excluded it from the form itself; you need to do that in PostForm.

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ['created_by']
```

As for assigning it automatically, the docs on the editing views have a [specific section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) describing exactly how to do this; you override `form_valid()`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
    return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: `exclude = ['CreatedBy']` resolved this issue. I did override all these methods since I wanted just the validation part in `form_valid` and form manipulation happening in a more apt place. But I missed form exclude attributes.Thanks for pointing me the right direction :)